# Between predicate for floating numbers

Tags: prolog

is there any built-in predicate like between for floating numbers? It is important that the predicate can also generate numbers. And if not, how can I write it for myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Not very clear what you want. Can you give examples of how it should work?

Comment: The predicate should handle queries like "between2(0.1, 0.7, R)" with R = 0.1, R = 0.2, R = 0.3, R = 0.4, R = 0.5, R = 0.6 and R = 0.7.

Comment: Is the "step" always 0.1, or how do you decide on that?

Comment: Yeah, the step should always be +0.1.

Comment: If those are supposed to be always decimals fractions with one digit after the decimal point, you can simply use arithmetic (*10 and /10) to convert between the decimals and the integers, then simply use `between/3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem. If you always have decimals, with one digit after the point, you can do:

```
between2(From, To, X) :-
    F is round(From * 10),
    T is round(To * 10),
    between(F, T, X0),
    X is X0 / 10. % this might fail if X is an integer
```

Your question title sounds much more general than this though. You can make a better question by explaining better what you want, and attempting to do it yourself. You can look for example at the [man page for `seq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) to help yourself decide on the interface.

Comment: When I ask for between2(0.2, 0.4, N), F becomes instantiated as 2.0 and T to 4.0 and it says "between/3: Type error: integer' expected, found 2.0 (a float)".

Comment: @zer0kai yes, of course, see the edit. But this approach is inherently broken (in my opinion).

Comment: @Boris: Much better than adding the [proverbial 0.1](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/disasters/patriot.html) in a row!